# Index for nullable column

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle, indexing

I have an index on a nullable column and I want to select all it's values like this:

```
SELECT e.ename 
FROM   emp e;
```

In the explain plan I see a `FULL TABLE SCAN` (even a hint didn't help)

```
SELECT e.ename 
FROM   emp e
WHERE  e.ename = 'gdoron';
```

Does use the index...

I googled and found out there are no null entries in indexes, thus the first query can't use the index.

My question is simple: **why there aren't null entries in indexes?**

Comment: As an aside, the full table can was performed in your first example as you were selecting a large percentage of the records from the table (in your case, 100%). Whether you had a Null-value index or not wouldn't matter the optimiser would have opted for a FTS for this query.

Comment: @Ollie. This why I wrote that I tried it again with a `hint` and it didn't help...

Comment: well, typical b-tree indexes won't include nulls.  Bitmap indexes will index nulls.

Comment: "I want to select all its values" can most likely be done by just adding `where e.ename is not null` to your first query. Of course, if you select any columns that can't be served just by the index you will end up with a FTS anyway (unless you force a hint, in which case it will use your index but you will actually have *worse* IO performance)

Comment: @Ollie -- if the index is on `ename`, which is the implication, it would be entirely possible for the optimizer to choose a full index scan instead of a full table scan, if not for the issue with `nulls`.

Comment: @Dave Costa, I know but the OP's example suggests he is returning all rows, nulls included, hence my answer. I probably could have made it clearer though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default, relational databases ignore NULL values (because the relational model says that NULL means "not present"). So, Index does not store NULL value, consequently if you have null condition in SQL statement, related index is ignored (by default).

But you can suprass this problem, check [THIS](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm) or [THIS](http://oradbatips.blogspot.com/2006/11/tip-8-index-for-null-columns.html) article.

Comment: I read this article, this is why I'm asking why this is working this way. It's weird.

Comment: Well think about this, in a index how can they distinct from all NULL's?

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting all of the rows from the table, why do you think it should use the index? A full table scan is the most efficient means to return all of the values. It has nothing to do with the nulls not being in the index and everything to do with the optimizer choosing the most efficient means of retrieving the data.

---

@A.B.Cade: It's possible that the optimizer could choose to use the index, but not likely. Let's say you've got a table with an indexed table with 100 rows, but only 10 values. If the optimizer uses the index, it has to get the 10 rows from the index, then expand it to 100 rows, whereas, with the full-table scan, it gets all 100 rows from the get-go. Here's an example:

```
create table test1 (blarg varchar2(10));

create index ak_test1 on test1 (blarg);

insert into test1
select floor(level/10) from dual connect by level<=100;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('testschema','test1');

exec dbms_stats.gather_index_stats('testschema','ak_test1');

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select * from test1;
```

My point is largely that this question is based largely on a flawed premise: that index-scans are intrinsically better that full-table scans. That is not always true, as this scenario demonstrates.

Comment: see DaveCosta 's comment. He's querying the index column - if not for the nulls it would have used a INDEX FULL SCAN

Comment: Well, we can't say that it definitely would have used the index, just that it could have.

Comment: I agree, but he did state in the question "(even a hint didn't help)"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the first query is pertinent in terms of index usage, at least the second could.

Anyway, while it is true that you cannot index a column containing a null value, there are ways to do it like for example:

```
create index MY_INDEX on emp(ename, 1);
```

notice the `, 1)` at the end which does the trick.

Comment: Didn't you mean: `create index MY_INDEX on emp(NVL(ename, 'null'));`

Comment: nope. comma followed by the digit 1 is the correct form. without the need to use nvl. nvl is another trick to use it but it forces the user to compare with the string 'null' if used as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be noted, [Bitmap-Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/schemas.htm#DWHSG9043) include rows that have NULL values.

**But you should not create Bitmap-Index just because you like to have NULL values in
your index.** Bitmap-Index indexes are intended for their use-case (see documentation)!

If you use them wrong, then your over-all performance may suffer significantly.