# Does PostgreSQL index null values?

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table like so:

```
Food
-----------------
name | price | x
```

Let's say I create an index on name & price, but the database has a bunch of null values for both name & price in some of the rows. Does PostgreSQL automatically skip indexing those rows?

Comment: Try inserting null values and check to see if it was indexed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index for nullable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175591/index-for-nullable-column)

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210292

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NULL values ARE indexed as well.

You can also use an index to speed up queries with a condition like

```
WHERE col IS NULL
```

Something that may come as a surprise to Oracle users is that you can have several rows with a NULL in a unique index. But that makes sense because `NULL = NULL` is not true.

Comment: Will such index work for `LEFT JOIN` queries?

Comment: @Klesun If you want to know if you can use an index to identify NULLs which are generated as the result of an outer join, no. These NULLs don't exist in the table, so they cannot be indexed. But an index can speed up a join for other reasons.